# Some redirects work, some don't...all same syntax?

Tags: .htaccess, syntax-error

OK, so I have an .htaccess file with over 4000 redirects for a Magento ecommerce store, some of the 301s work and some don't.

Here's a sample:

```
redirect 301 /1-watt-12-volt-led-bullet-spotlight.aspx http://www.my-new-webstore.com

redirect 301 /1-watt-12-volt-led-waterfall-light.aspx http://www.my-new-webstore.com
```

The second one is returning a 500 error, why? It's almost exactly the same as the one above it (just a different product); when I put them both live it returns a 500 error but when I comment it out, no error.

Could there be some other file not enabling the redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe you should think about some other way of managing the 4000+ redirects other than using an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-new-webstore.com [R=301,L]
```

For all of them, or something like

```
RewriteRule ^1-watt-12(.*) http://www.my-new-webstore.com/1-watt-12$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you need things more precise (haven't checked last one, and is written from memory, so read the docs if it doesn't work!)